# Getting input without pausing the snake game?

Tags: c++

I am beginner in c++. I want to write snake game without graphics.The problem i am facing is that whenever i try to get the input it pauses the snake.I am using Dev c++ compiler. Any idea?

Comment: How do you make a snake game without graphics? Also, you're going to need to learn about multithreading for this (just the basics).

Comment: @DavidGrinberg ncurses and/or VT-100 escape sequences. the game was around before CGA arrived :)

Comment: question is too vauge, you should have mentioned ncurses in your question and show you're displaying text + getting input

Comment: OP does not mention a platform or other details which would allow useful advice to be given, aside from "Dev c++", which is perhaps Windows (see [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/)).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use polling,
All standard input functions are blocking but you can use OS specific input method.
i.e for windows you can use GetKeyboardState()